# C Programming output text file

Tags: c, file, output

Hi I just started programming and have a beginner question:
I would like to better understand how the fprint()function work because sometimes when I create a text file with it, I realized there are various types of file eg.(read only, append and write). And when I want to write on the file I created with a loop, the order in which the content is added seem to change when I do

```
file = fopen(name,"a+");
```

And I cannot add all the content in the loop if it is

```
file = fopen(name,"w");
```

So what's the most convenient way to create a text file?
Thank you!

So say I want to write all the words from a trie tree, the order in the text file would be different than just replacing fprint() with print()
I have a global node for the tree and a node pointer pointing to it for other functions

```
struct node *root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

And the function is:

```
void printResult(struct node* r){
struct node *p = r;
FILE *file;
sprintf(name, "man%d.txt", num);
file = fopen(name,"a+");
int i=0;
int temp;
while(i!=26){
 if(p->child[i]==NULL){
  i++;
  continue;}
 if(p->child[i]->isword==1&&p->child[i]->leaf==1){
  word[k]=i+'a';
  word[k+1]='\0';
  fprintf(file,"%s", word);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d", p->child[i]->occurrence);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d\n", p->child[i]->super);
  i++;
  continue;} 
 if(p->child[i]->isword==0){
  word[k]=i+'a';
  temp=k;
  k++;
  p=p->child[i];
  printResult(p);
  k=temp;
  p=p->parent;
  }
 if(p->child[i]->isword==1&&p->child[i]->leaf==0){
  word[k]=i+'a';
  word[k+1]='\0';
  temp=k;
  k++;
  p->child[i]->isword=0;
  fprintf(file,"%s", word);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d", p->child[i]->occurrence);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d\n", p->child[i]->super);
  p=p->child[i];
  printResult(p);
  k=temp;
  p=p->parent;
}
 i++;
}fclose(file);
}
```

And the node:

```
struct node{   
struct node * parent;
int noempty;
int isword;
int super;
int occurrence;
int leaf;
struct node * child[26];
};
```

Lastly it's the insert function

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root,char *c){
int i=0;
struct node *temp=root;
int l=length(c);
while(i!=l){
int index=c[i]-'a';
if(temp->child[index]==NULL){
//New Node
struct node *n=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
n->parent=temp;
temp->child[index]=n;
temp->noempty=1;}
//Node Exist
if(i!=l&&temp->leaf==1){temp->leaf=0;}
temp=temp->child[index];
i++;}
if(temp->noempty==0){
temp->leaf=1;}
temp->isword=1;
return root;
 };
```

Comment: I do not understand your question.  If you open the file with mode "a", then all writes will go to the end of the file.  If you open with mode "w", then all writes will go to wherever the current position is when you do the write.  if you open with mode "r", then writes will fail.  The "most convenient" way to create the file depends on how you want writes to behave.  Probably `fopen(name, "w")` is most convenient.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  What if I want to create a file and write to the top of the file? I am trying to write a function, when I use print(), the order is correct, but when I use fprint() to write them on a file with the same order it doesn't work and the order seem really random.

Comment: What do you mean by 'write to the top of the file'?  If you mean 'change the first line repeatedly', it is doable (but not with `"a"` mode).  If you mean 'insert a line at the start of the file (pushing the previous lines down the file)', then it is not sensibly doable; it rapidly gets very expensive.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in the comment, what I meant was to write the content line by line

Comment: OK; phew.  You write some data with `fprintf()` or any other suitable set of functions; you ensure there's a newline at the end; you go back and write the next line.  There's normally no need for anything fancy.  Lines are added as you print the data.  You need to show your code so we have some idea of the problems you're having, because writing to a text file sequentially, adding new lines at the end, is about as straight-forward as it gets.  Please read about how to produce an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Then update your question with some code that illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer Thanks, I edit the question and add the code I am working on. I am trying to write all the words from  tried tree into a file.

Comment: Thanks for the update — sort of.  Please re-read the description of an MCVE ([MCVE]) because what you've added doesn't look like an MCVE all of a sudden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136915/discussion-between-ghostkid-yao-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: The five calls — `fprintf(file,"%s", word);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d", p->child[i]->occurrence);fprintf(file,"%s"," " );
  fprintf(file,"%d\n", p->child[i]->super);` — should be one call: ` fprintf(file,"%s %d %s\n", word, p->child[i]->occurrence, p->child[i]->super);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136915/discussion-between-ghostkid-yao-and-jonathan-leffler), we came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define length(x) strlen(x)

struct node
{
    struct node *parent;
    int noempty;
    int isword;
    int super;
    int occurrence;
    int leaf;
    struct node *child[26];
};

static struct node *root = 0;
static char word[1024];
static int k = 0;

static
void printResult(FILE * file, struct node *r)
{
    struct node *p = r;
    int i = 0;
    int temp;
    while (i != 26)
    {
        if (p->child[i] == NULL)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (p->child[i]->isword == 1 && p->child[i]->leaf == 1)
        {
            word[k] = i + 'a';
            word[k + 1] = '\0';
            fprintf(file, "%s", word);
            fprintf(file, "%s", " ");
            fprintf(file, "%d", p->child[i]->occurrence);
            fprintf(file, "%s", " ");
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", p->child[i]->super);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (p->child[i]->isword == 0)
        {
            word[k] = i + 'a';
            temp = k;
            k++;
            p = p->child[i];
            printResult(file, p);
            k = temp;
            p = p->parent;
        }
        if (p->child[i]->isword == 1 && p->child[i]->leaf == 0)
        {
            word[k] = i + 'a';
            word[k + 1] = '\0';
            temp = k;
            k++;
            p->child[i]->isword = 0;
            fprintf(file, "%s", word);
            fprintf(file, "%s", " ");
            fprintf(file, "%d", p->child[i]->occurrence);
            fprintf(file, "%s", " ");
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", p->child[i]->super);
            p = p->child[i];
            printResult(file, p);
            k = temp;
            p = p->parent;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

static
struct node *insert(struct node *root, char *c)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct node *temp = root;
    int l = length(c);
    while (i != l)
    {
        int index = c[i] - 'a';
        if (temp->child[index] == NULL)
        {
// New Node
            struct node *n = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            n->parent = temp;
            temp->child[index] = n;
            temp->noempty = 1;
        }
// Node Exist
        if (i != l && temp->leaf == 1)
        {
            temp->leaf = 0;
        }
        temp = temp->child[index];
        i++;
    }
    if (temp->noempty == 0)
    {
        temp->leaf = 1;
    }
    temp->isword = 1;
    return root;
}

int main(void)
{
    root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memset(root, '\0', sizeof(*root));

    char line[1024];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", line);
        root = insert(root, line);
    }

    FILE *file;
    char name[1024];
    int num = 0;
    sprintf(name, "man%d.txt", num);
    file = fopen(name, "w");

    printResult(file, root);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Given input file:

```
elephant
rhinoceros
mouse
```

the output in `man0.txt` was:

```
elephant 0 0
mouse 0 0
rhinoceros 0 0
```

This isn't dreadfully exciting; each word starts at its own node.

Similarly, given the input:

```
boo
book
booking
john
tex
text
```

the output was:

```
boo 0 0
book 0 0
booking 0 0
john 0 0
tex 0 0
text 0 0
```

It seems that the task specified that `printResults()` could take no arguments.  That makes life extraordinarily difficult with a recursive function.  The code shown passes a node to the function — and also the file stream to write to.  It uses `"w"` to open the file rather than `"a+"`.  Since the file was never read, the `+` was not needed; using `"a"` instead of `"w"` means that the information was appended to the file from the previous run.

There are too many globals; there were more when I started.  `k` should not still be a global, but I've not removed it yet.

Answer (score 1):

> what's the most convenient way to create a text file?
>
> I want to write all the words from a trie tree, the order in the text file would be different than just replacing fprint() with print() I have a global node for the tree and a node pointer pointing to it for other functions

In order to most conveniently write a trie to disk, it'll help massively if you can refer to the *entire* trie as an array. i.e. Don't just have a `root` that leads to separate allocations; have *everything* refer back to the same array! Then it is as simple as writing nodes straight from the array to the disk, providing you don't need to translate integers for other implementations, or translating integers for other implementations otherwise... and you won't need to worry about the differences between `a+` and `w`.

There are other benefits to using a single allocation:

- One allocation means one free, which doubly means your code will be much faster. (Actually, no allocation is necessary as you'll see below)
- Cache consistency; a single allocation is likely to be cached better as one entry rather than multiple allocations. This will lead to less cache misses in a portable way, and less non-portable manual optimisation required as a result. Again, your code will be faster.
- How many C-standard functions actually allocate memory behind the scenes? None, except for the memory allocation functions, of course... **How does this benefit you, as the user of those functions?** If you think about it, **you can write your code `malloc`-free**, so *the caller decides* what type of allocation to use (be it automatic storage duration, static storage duration, `malloc`/`realloc`) similar to how `scanf`, `strcat`, `sprintf`, etc lets you choose... This makes things *much easier* to test, for example you can check [my PATRICIA trie test code](https://github.com/Sebbyastian/patricia/blob/master/patricia_test.c) and [my PATRICIA library code](https://github.com/Sebbyastian/patricia/blob/master/patricia.c) to see I don't need to test using `malloc` and `free`, which makes testing look cleaner obviously... Not to mention, there are usecases where `malloc` and `free` aren't the best choices!

The last point is particularly useful, as it allows the caller to store data within the trie nodes as an extension, rather than pointing to the data externally as you've done. This makes it even easier to write your file, as you could technically just dump the entire array to the file in one foul swoop if all of the information is there. Food for thought: Do you suppose a disk-based trie using RAM as a level of cache might be doable?

Comment: The file functions typically allocate memory for buffers and the like.  The allocated memory is, of course, released by `fclose()` without other user intervention.

Comment: Right you are, @JonathanLeffler. Various thread-related functions also allocate resources. They're few and far between, however, and it seems weren't particularly well designed for that reason. Who'd ever want an array of `FILE`, hmmm? ;)